# facebook integration for android is hectic process in eclipse

Tags: android, facebook

I have tried to integrate FacebookSDK in eclipse, but its a really hectic process.
The Eclipse all the time giving an error, I have watched the tutorials, and According to them and developers.facebook.com,  all we need to do is clean and build the project in Eclipse.
I have done that thousands of times, but same thing happens, either Exclamatory mark come with FacebookSDK or Some unusual errors.
I have tried in 2 ways :

1) **File -> Import -> Existing Project Into Workspace**
   which gives the Imported Project name as ***FacebookSDK*** with exclamatory sign.
(Project Properties -> Android -> Is Library checked  and Java Compiler -> JDK compliance ->1.6)
I have cleaned,built, but unusual error comes.

2) **File -> New -> Android Project -> Create Project From Existing Source -> (Browse the SDK downloaded from developers.facebook.com)**
   Now, this gives the project name as **com_facebook_android**

Can anyone tell me , proper way to integrate Facebook for Android ?[image]

Comment: did you run "eclipse -clean" That one solves alot of eclipse issues on it's own :)

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question.  Can you edit and add details of exactly what errors you are getting - eg. the output from the build process.

Comment: i have added the FacebookSDK and The newly created project has attached FacebookSDK library (Project Properties->Android->Add->(Choose FacebookSDK)), but when i declare Facebook object and initialise it by passing APP_ID, it gives error - "Your Project Contains Error", but the newly created project doesnt show any error over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved , i was using older Eclipse version, Downloaded New Eclipse(juno) 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ 
And updated ADT to 21 and SDK.

Then followed the procedure from developers.facebook.com and Bingo !!

Answer (score 0):

```
your step 1) and 2) are correct but you have to do more step...i give u proper step:

Facebook Integeration

Go to github and download Facebook sdk
Extract to C drive. Import to eclipse, Select Facebook
Your App > Right click > Properties>Android>Library>Facebook
You need to get AppID  
                ------ To create facebook android native app you need to provide your Android application signature in facebook app settings. You can generate your application signature (keyhash) using keytool that comes with java. But to generate signature you need openssl installed on your pc. If you don’t have one download openssl and set it in your system environment path.

5. Download openssl
--------Open your command prompt (CMD) and run the following command to generate your keyhash.

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "&lt;path-to-users-directory&gt;\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64



...keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\deepika\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64.............

After generating your app signature successfully, register your facebook application by going to create new facebook application and fill out all the information needed. And select Native Android App and give your hashkey there which you generated previously using keytool and note down your facebook App ID

6.Generate Access-Token

----To obtain an App Access Token, perform an HTTP GET on:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
   client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
  &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
  &grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: i think you didnt get my question. i can generate Hash key, the steps you mentioned , the problem is the imported project shows unusual errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Project Build Target for FacebookSDK? Under Properties->Android, after right-clicking on the FacebookSDK project.

Comment: What error messages do you get if you open the FacebookSDK source files? (wanted to make this answer a comment, but my rep is too low so I'm only allowed to post answers or comments to my own answers)

Comment: the First line in AccessToken.java file import android.annotation.SuppressLint; which is giving error, The import annotation can not be resolved. and many more

Comment: What happens if you change the build target for FacebookSDk to Android 4.0.3 (which is used by your own project)?